# How to force dateFormat to take exactly the specified number of characters as valid?

Tags: java, date, formatting, simpledateformat

The following code...

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
df.setLenient(false);
Date date = df.parse("2012115");
```

...parses the string `"2012115"` to the Date equivalent of November 5th, 2012. I want it to fail parsing, because it is missing one day character. In other words, I only want the string `"20121105"` to evaluate to that date. Is there a way to enforce this, other than evaluating the length of the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...parses the string "2012115" to the Date equivalent of November 5th, 2012. I want it to fail parsing, because it is missing one day character. In other words, I only want the string "20121105" to evaluate to that date.

**I doubt you could do it using the formatter only.** As a workaround, you may want to put a check on the date string length before parsing as below:

```
      String dateString = "2012115";
      String formatString = "yyyyMMdd";
      if(dateString == null || dateString.length() != formatString.length()){
         throw new ParseException("Invalid Date Input", 0);
      }
      SimpleDateFormat formatter= new SimpleDateFormat(formatString);
      formatter.setLenient(false);
      Date date = df.parse(dateString);
```

Comment: Thanks, Yogendra---that's what I thought. I'll wait a bit longer before marking your answer as correct, in the hopes that it isn't ;-).

Answer (score 1):

You could actually format it again and check if they are the same

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
df.setLenient(false);
String dstr = "2012115";
Date date = df.parse(dstr);
String newdstr = df.format (date);
if (!newdstr.equals(dstr)) {
   throw new ParseException ("bla bla");
}
```

Comment: I know it's an old answer, but I just have to admit, that it's pretty clever and it works perfectly in my case.